# In Rails, why do .sass files magically get recompiled into .css files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I didn't invoke any sass command to "watch" the .sass file changes and recompile them into .css (and concatenate all .css into a giant .css file)
But somehow, when I modify any .sass file in the Rails project, and reload the page on a browser, the giant .css file already has the updated content. 
What is the mechanism that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `gem 'haml'` in your Gemfile, it's that.

The gem's [init.rb](http://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/master/init.rb) file gets run which calls [`Haml.init_rails`](http://github.com/nex3/haml/blob/master/lib/haml.rb), and you can follow the thread from there pretty easily.

Comment: does it happen per page request or per partial?  our page takes 30 to 40 seconds to render, I am not sure why the 3ms, 12ms partial render time all add up to feel like 5 seconds (it could be controller code too)

Comment: I'm not positive but it should be per-request (similar to way Rails reloads classes). In your original post you say "giant .css file" - how "giant" are we talking? In my projects that use Sass, the re-compile times are negligible, so I'd be surprised if this is causing slow loading for you.

Comment: It's not per page request per se. It's everytime the sass file changes, and of course never when you run your app with RAILS_ENV set to production.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't clear but that's what I meant - each request it checks for Sass changes. It's not constantly polling the filesystem, or something.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you're curious how SASS determines if a file should be updated (I was). It checks the mtime of the compiled CSS files (if the compiled file doesn't exist, it obviously creates it). Here's the class that handles checking the staleness of compiled CSS:

https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/lib/sass/plugin/staleness_checker.rb